# How to initialize intitial_state for LSTM in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am not sure how to pass a value for initial_state when the cell is a LSTMCell. I am using LSTMStateTuple as it is shown in the following piece of code:

```
c_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [ None, config.state_dim], name='c_lstm')

h_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [ None, config.state_dim], name='h_lstm')

state_tuple = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(c_placeholder, h_placeholder)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=config.state_dim, state_is_tuple=True, reuse=not is_training)  

rnn_outs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=x,sequence_length=seqlen, initial_state=state_tuple, dtype= tf.float32)
```

However, the execution returns this error:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

Here is the link of the documentation for [dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this same error before. I was using multiple layers of RNN-cells made with `tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell`, and I needed to specify a tuple of `LSTMStateTuples` -- one for each layer. Something like

```
state = tuple(
        [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(c_ph[i], h_ph[i])
         for i in range(nRecurrentLayers)]
    )
```